# Angular 6: Route path appends after query string

Tags: angular

My condition is like that my app is loading inside the iframe. So first it will read the query string from URL and redirect app based on the value. But every time it does that it append the route path to the end of the query string. My Code.

## app.component

```
 ngOnInit(){
 if (conditionmatch) {
    this.router.navigate(['template-not-found'])
  }
}
```

## routing.module

```
{ path: 'template-not-found', component: TemplateNotFoundComponent },
```

For example my initial condition is https://localhost:44351/id=152&projId=130
So after condition match it goes to that page but it appends route path at the end. https://localhost:44351/id=152&projId=130#/template-not-found

How should i handle this so that it comes before the query string?

Answer (score 0):

To navigate relative to the root you have to put a slash before the first segment path.

So try

```
ngOnInit(){
 if (conditionmatch) {
    this.router.navigate(['/template-not-found'])
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use the slash what URL is it navigating to?

Comment: Its navigate to the correct page but on the URL i see the routepath  appended at the end of query string. https://localhost:44351/id=152&projId=130#/template-not-found

Comment: I see a # sign in our URL. So my guess is that you are using the LocationHashStategy. You query parameters come before the # sign. Angular assumes anything before the # sign is part of the main URL and it wont change it

Comment: okay. that might be the region. I will see making changes based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using relative routes. You are wanting to use an absolute route, so you need to put a slash in front of your route like so:
`this.router.navigate(['/template-not-found'])`